# Find the generating function for the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$, with $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1.$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

This was a test question and I felt confident about it but all he put on it was no and circled a problem and left it at that. My solution up until I messed up which was early was

$G_a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

$G_a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})x^n$

$G_a(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2}x^n + a_0+a_1$

in the second line he circled n=0 in the sum and and then in the third line he wrote n=2 instead of n=1 in the first sum. Can anyone explain and show me how to solve it the correct way.

My final answer was $G_a(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x-1} $

Comment: The recurrence relation only holds for $n\ge 2$. Jumping to your third line, you have reversed the sign on the second sum. The first sum should be from $n=2$. You have taken care of the first two terms (n=0,1) by adding them at the end. Now you need to write the sums as things like $xG_a(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

With as much detail as possible,
$$\begin{align*} G_a(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \\ &= a_0 x^0 + a_1 x^1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n x^n \\ &= a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) x^n \\ &= a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-1} x^n - \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2} x^n \\ &= a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+2} \\ &= a_0 + a_1 x + x \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n - x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \\ &= a_0 + a_1 x + x \left( -a_0 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \right) - x^2 G_a(x) \\ &= a_0 + a_1 x + x(-a_0 + G_a(x)) - x^2 G_a(x) \\ &= a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x + (x - x^2)G_a(x). \end{align*}$$  Therefore, $$G_a(x) = \frac{a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x}{1 - x + x^2}.$$

Comment: In spite of appearances, our solutions are the same but finding different ways. Your $G_a(x)$ is my red answer with the given initial conditions. Best regards.

Comment: @Piquito My answer is intended to address the specific question of why the calculation provided in the original post was marked as incorrect, and what the correct calculation along the same lines would be, rather than to furnish a complete solution by any other means.

Comment: I just set me on the title to find the generating function so your answer is better than mine  even though I go directly and easily to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can verify a certain periodicity in the terms without solving the recurrence $a_n$. In fact $$a_0=0\\a_1=1\\a_2=1\\a_3=0\\a_4=-1\\a_5=-1\\a_6=0\\a_7=1$$ Hence the sequence of values can be considered as beginning again from $a_6$ and $a_7$; an so on....

Consequently the asked generating function is

$$\color{red}{F(x)=(x+x^2-x^4-x^5)+(x^7+x^8-x^{10}-x^{11})+(x^{13}+x^{14}-x^{16}-x^{17}) +.....}$$

Considering finitely many terms, in order to get a closed form, we have $$F(x)=(x+x^2-x^4-x^5)(1+x^6+x^{12}+x^{18}+.....+x^{6n})$$

$$F(x)=(x+x^2-x^4-x^5)\left(\frac{x^{6(n+1)}-1}{x^6-1}\right)$$

Finally $$F(x)=(x-x^4)(x+1)\left(\frac{x^{6(n+1)}-1}{x^6-1}\right)=-x(x^3-1)(x+1)\left(\frac{x^{6(n+1)}-1}{x^6-1}\right)=x(x+1)\left(\frac{1-x^{6(n+1)}}{x^3+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution :
Given the definition of a generating function:
$A(z)=a_{0}+a_{1}\cdot z+a_{2}\cdot z^{2}\ldots={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cdot z^{n}}$
$a_{-n}=0|n>0$
Your problem, as a constraint, is $a_{n}-a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=0$
$\left(z^{2}-z+1\right)A(z)=a_{0}+a_{1}\cdot z=0+1\cdot z$
Which means that all three term sums are zero starting from the first three.
This leaves two “initial conditions”/starters undefined as: $a_{0},a_{1}$
And the solution is:
$A(z)=\frac{z}{\left(z^{2}-z+1\right)}$
So you had a sign mistake.  Unless these problems are done in a simple transparent manner it is hard to spot that type of thing.